# How could I limit the amount of items in an array (js)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
let items = querySnapshot.docs.map(post => {
  if(xy < 20){
return `<div id="postBox">
  <h4 id="postName">${post.data().display_name}</h4>
  <h1 id="postTitle">${post.data().title}</h1>
  <h3 id="postDescription">${post.data().description}</h3>
  <h5 id="postId">post id:${post.id}<h5>
      <h6 id="postUid">uid:${post.data().uid}<h6>
  <div id="likeContainer"><ion-icon name="thumbs-up-outline" id="likeBtn"></ion-icon><h3 id="likeCount">${post.data().likes}</h3></div>
  </div>`
  xy = xy + 1;
}
});
```

I would like to make it so the array has 20 items.

Comment: You can also use [`limitToFirst(20)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Query#limittofirst) or [`limitToLast(20)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Query#limittolast) on your query that feeds the `querySnapshot`. If you want to search other ways to deal with subsets of results from Firestore, search for the term "pagination".

Comment: I am using firestore for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take only a max of 20 items, then do the map. If there are more than 20 items, it will max out at 20, if there are less it won't insert empty items.

```js
let items = querySnapshot.docs.slice(0, 20).map(post => {
  return `<div id="postBox">
    <h4 id="postName">${post.data().display_name}</h4>
    <h1 id="postTitle">${post.data().title}</h1>
    <h3 id="postDescription">${post.data().description}</h3>
    <h5 id="postId">post id:${post.id}<h5>
    <h6 id="postUid">uid:${post.data().uid}<h6>
    <div id="likeContainer"><ion-icon name="thumbs-up-outline" id="likeBtn"></ion-icon><h3 id="likeCount">${post.data().likes}</h3></div>
  </div>`;
});
```

```js
const data1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(data1.slice(0, 20).map(n => `number ${n}`));

const data2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25];

console.log(data2.slice(0, 20).map(n => `number ${n}`));
```

Comment: If I run this I just get a bunch of empty items: let items = querySnapshot.docs.slice(-1, -20).map(post => {
  return `<div id="postBox">
    <h4 id="postName">${post.data().display_name}</h4>
    <h1 id="postTitle">${post.data().title}</h1>
    <h3 id="postDescription">${post.data().description}</h3>
    <h5 id="postId">post id:${post.id}<h5>
    <h6 id="postUid">uid:${post.data().uid}<h6>
    <div id="likeContainer"><ion-icon name="thumbs-up-outline" id="likeBtn"></ion-icon><h3 id="likeCount">${post.data().likes}</h3></div>
  </div>`;
});

Comment: why do you have negative numbers? if you're wanting to get the last 20, do `.slice(-20)`, and if you want them to reverse order, do `.reverse()` afterwards. `.slice(-1, -20)` is not valid

Comment: ... is not valid because, in an array with 33 elements, it would be the same as `.slice(33, 24)`